# Java httpget seems to work but encountering 401 error

Tags: java, http, authentication, http-get

HAve re-written due to the feedback so far...

I'ev got a Java method to try and download a file via httpget within a selenium script, it looks like so...

```
 private String downloader(WebElement element, String attribute, String filePath) throws IOException, NullPointerException, URISyntaxException {      
        String fileToDownloadLocation = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        fileToDownloadLocation = fileToDownloadLocation.replace("\\", "%5C");
        URL fileToDownload = new URL(fileToDownloadLocation);
        URI FileDL = new URI(fileToDownload.toString());


        File downloadedFile = new File(this.localDownloadPath + filePath);
        if (downloadedFile.canWrite() == false) downloadedFile.setWritable(true);

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new NTCredentials("useraccount", "testpassword", "machinename", "mydomain"));

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(FileDL);        

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);

        this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();

        String downloadedFileAbsolutePath = downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return downloadedFileAbsolutePath;
}
```

When I use this on a regular link (i.e. downloading a file from the bbc for example) it all works.  The trouble is the system I'm using it on is an internal one that uses windows authentication to determine if access is permitted.  When I attempt to use it on this internal system my Http response ends up reading: -

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Type: text/html, Expires: -1, Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5, WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge, Date: Mon, 17 Mar 2014 14:52:43 GMT, Content-Length: 1293]
```

If I debug this and obtain the URL it uses I can manually paste this into a browser and it works fine.

I also noticed that during debug the httpRequestParameters doesn't seem to have any values in in at all (shows as null) so I'm guessing that I'm still not setting the account parameters properly somehow.

I'll be honest and say I'm really not 100% on what all this does properly and am trying to paste things together and get it to play ball but I'm wondering if the section where I have `((AbstractHttpClient) client).getCredentialsProvider().` is set up properly or if I'm missing something here...

Any further help much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you need credentials to actually download the file. You can view it in a browser without any credentials.

Comment: Yep viewing it works fine, if I go to the link manually I can view it and the go through the usual process to download it without any problem or credentials being required but I'm guessing attempting to download the file in this manner requires credentials and I have no idea how to specify those... :S

Comment: Maybe contact whoever runs the website you want to download from.

Comment: The website is internal, and I know what username/Password to use to be able to access it, I just don't know how to set them :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to get my code working, the final version is shown above.  I'd made a few obvious errors such as my domain was still set to the examples "microsoft.com" and I had actually misspelled my password, other than that it now does exactly what I need it to! :)

@vzamanillo thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the BASIC authentication credentials in two different ways:

Setting the appropiated HTTP header:

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://...");

String basic_auth = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
get.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + basic_auth);
```

or using the `CredentialsProvider` (depends on the Apache HttpComponents version)

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

hc.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

HttpGet get = new HttpGet ("http://...");       

hc.execute(get);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, other things took over.  when I try to implement the second example I get an issue at the `getCredentialsProvider` line, Eclipse tells me `The method getCredentialsProvider() is undefined for the type HttpClient` and that I need to Add cast to hc

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Of Eclipse?  Indigo service release 1.

Comment: It looks like if I add the cast like it suggests it seems to work ok, however when I run the execute I then get an error reading `org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication process
SEVERE: Authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))`

Comment: What kind of authentication you need to use, HTTP BASIC or what?

Comment: The website uses windows authentication I believe (i.e. it uses the account credentials that the user is currently logged in with to validate against).  The account that I'm running the program under has access  (i.e. I can manually go to that URL and it works fine).  I've updated my code above to reflect the changes I've made in light of your earlier suggestions.

Comment: I noticed when I look at the value of `response` during debug I get the string `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Type: text/html, Expires: -1, Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5, WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge, Date: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 14:24:16 GMT, Content-Length: 1293]`

Comment: What version of Apache http components are you using?

Comment: Do you mean within my java program or the one on the website side that I'm trying to access?  On my side I've got the jar apache-mime4j-0.6.jar in my build path.